# Div onclick function not running as expected

Tags: jquery, html, onclick

I'm trying to run a function that activates whenever anywhere on the webpage is clicked.

In order to achieve this I created a div that fills the full webpage and I set an onclick command, but there's no response when clicking the div.

The exact same function works when I use it in an 'onclick' on a button, so what am I doing wrong?

`<div id='target' onclick="getStatus()">
<button onclick="getStatus()">Start</button>`

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How would we know? You haven't shown us your code.

Comment: The code is right there in the question, the only relevant code I haven't shown is what the function does and that doesn't need to be known in order to get this working.

Comment: You haven't shown us your click handler. That's what's relevant here.

Comment: Click handler?
The 2nd line of code works for the button and all it needs is that one line. My question is why doesn't the 1st line work for a div and how to get it working.
Is the syntax incorrect?

Comment: Div elements don't have click events. That's why we use jQuery. Also, it's best practice to use event handlers outside your markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that empty divs dont take up any space try fiddling your css and adding

```
div{
    display: block;
    height: 1280px;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
 }
```

Hope this is what you wanted.
Without style:
https://jsfiddle.net/L702aaha/
With style:
https://jsfiddle.net/v58urpe3/1/

Comment: " ... I created a div that fills the full webpage ... "

Comment: hope this proves it.

Comment: Sorry isherwood is right, I've added your code to make sure the div definitely fills the full webpage and still no response when I click it.

Comment: Can you check the fiddle links. It clearly shows it works.

Comment: If it still doesn't help. Can you tell what area is covered by your div, if any by inspecting the element in chrome.

Comment: I used IE f12, the whole page is taken up by the div

Comment: Also I tried the fiddle links, the 2nd one works but the first doesn't
Do you think it needs a style?

Comment: I am not sure about IE, sorry for my inability to access one rite now, but if you try chrome and Firefox. You'll definitely get what I am talking about. Yeah the **first one** won't work it has **no css** for div. **So div occupies no space**. Hope this helps

Comment: Got it working now :)
The div just needed a stylesheet.
Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

You can use vanilla javascript to achieve the effect of clicking. Here is a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/hjamal/16geab29/

The Mouse event that gets passed has an srcElement property so you can control whether or not to react when the user presses on an inner element or the outer element.

You can also use `document.addEventListener('click', callback)` in lieu of making a div that wraps the whole document to listen for clicks in the entire document and use the same trick as above to make it behave differently for each element inside the document.

If you pull up your developer console on this page for an example and copy this code in you should get similar behavior to what you desire.

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  var source =  event.srcElement || event.target;  
  console.log(source)
})
```

Please note that srcElement is not standardized anywhere. Also old versions of IE use target instead. To learn more look at the following:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/srcElement
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event

Comment: I tried the event listener both inside a function and outside of the function.
When outside I get no response and when inside I get: Unable to get property 'addEventListener' of undefined or null reference

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by " inside a function and outside of the function." I added more info to my answer to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick="getStatus()"">
```

Is referring to a `getStatus` function that should exist somewhere on your page within a script tag.

e.g.

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    func getStatus(){
//your code in here
}

});

</script>
```

Comment: It does exist: function getStatus() { etc.}
There's nothing wrong with the function as when I tell it to run from a button press it runs (as shown in the question)